# How to create a dictionary where each key has 2 values each?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists as follows.

```
stocks  = ["ACC" , "RELIANCE" , "YESBANK"]
strings = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
```

I want to create a dictionary where "ACC" has first 2 elements of strings as its values

so my desired output shall be

```
{"ACC":["A","B"],"RELIANCE":["C","D"],"YESBANK":["E","F"]}
```

Answer (score 3):

One-liner:

```
d = {stock: strings[2*i:2*i+2] for i, stock in enumerate(stocks)}
```

Output on interpreter session:

```
>>> stocks  = ["ACC" , "RELIANCE" , "YESBANK"]
>>> strings = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
>>> 
>>> d = {stock: strings[2*i:2*i+2] for i, stock in enumerate(stocks)}
>>> d
{'ACC': ['A', 'B'], 'RELIANCE': ['C', 'D'], 'YESBANK': ['E', 'F']}  # Desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

> In python, a dictionary can only hold a single value for a given key.
>   However, if you use a relevant data type for that value, you should be
>   able to save multiple values for a single key.

you can simply use another dictionary as the value

```
dict = {
    "my_key": {
        "one": value_1, 
        "two": value_2
    }
}
print (dict["my_key"]["one"])
print (dict["my_key"]["two"])
```

Check this [link](https://www.quora.com/In-the-Python-dictionary-can-1-key-hold-more-than-1-value) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

```
stocks  = ["ACC" , "RELIANCE" , "YESBANK"]
strings = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
i = 0
y = {}
for comp in stocks:
    y[comp] = [strings[i], strings[i+1]]
    i += 2
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generator here:

```
gen = (slice(i-2, i) for i in range(2, len(strings) + 1, 2)) #makes a generator of slices like 0:2, 2:4 etcs

dict_1 = {i: strings[next(gen)] for i in stocks} # slices the `strings` list and put them as values for each elem. of `stocks`
print(dict_1)
```

**Output**

```
{'ACC': ['A', 'B'], 'RELIANCE': ['C', 'D'], 'YESBANK': ['E', 'F']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method that groups your second list by 2 elements:

```
def chunks2(lst):
    """Yield successive 2-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
        yield lst[i:i + 2]
```

then use a dictionary comprehension to get your desired output:

```
stocks  = ["ACC" , "RELIANCE" , "YESBANK"]
strings = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

desired_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(stocks, chunks2(strings))}

print(desired_dict)
```

**output**:

```
{'ACC': ['A', 'B'], 'RELIANCE': ['C', 'D'], 'YESBANK': ['E', 'F']}
```